# Blazor Render Fragment Child Content to allow only certain components?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Is it possible to restrict the RenderFragment Child Content of a component to only  allow certain components?
For example

```
<MyParentComponent>
 <Children>
  <AcceptedChild/>
  <InvalidChild/> <-- throw err since it shouldn't be accepted
 </Children>
</MyParentComponent>
```

EDIT:

```
<DataGrid>
 <DataGridColumns>
  <DataGridColumn/>
  <DataGridColumn/>
  <NotADataGridColumn/> <--- throw error
 </DataGridColumns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: This looks like it could be a feature request. You can match singular templates by name, this would require an array notation. But when the Parent comp (here: DataGridColumns) uses ChildContent you lose control over what is allowed.

Comment: This example of using ChildContent with templates might be helpful: https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/passing-data-to-a-renderfragement/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to restrict the RenderFragment Child Content of a component to only allow certain components?

No.

A `RenderFragment` is a delegate.  In your example the `RenderFragment` assigned to `DataGridColumns` belongs to the parent page/component, not `DataGrid`, and is run in the context of the parent by the Renderer.  `DataGrid` only "knows" it as a delegate that conforms to the `RenderFragment` pattern.  It has no access to the internal code, so has no way of knowing what it contains.

Comment: But you can already match a singular element by name. We would need a `[Parameter] DataGridColumn[]` and then _no_ ChildContent to make it an error.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `[Parameter] public RenderFragment CustomComponent { get; set; }` it will only allow only CustomComponent to be passed but not as component means you can't pass parameters to `CustomComponent` here is the issue opened on blazor github but unfortunatily is not planned for .net 7 release.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12302

Comment: I wouldn't hold you breath!. This is classified as a feature, not an issue.  It's been kicked down the road so far.  If you start to analyse how to implement it, you can understand why!

Answer (score 1):

If your component contains two or more `RenderFragment` parameters, you can limit the valid selection of direct children when using your component.

E.g. if you have a component `MyComponent` with the following parameters:

```csharp
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment FirstChild { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public RenderFragment SecondChild { get; set; }
```

and you try to use it as follows:

```csharp
<MyComponent>
    <FirstChild />
    <SecondChild />
    <ThirdChild />
</MyComponent>
```

`<ThirdChild />` will throw error:

> RZ9996 Unrecognized child content inside component 'MyComponent'. The component 'MyComponent' accepts child content through the following top-level items: 'MyFirstChildComponent', 'MySecondChildComponent'.

---

The equivalent in your example would be that `Children` e.g. contains parameters `RenderFragment AcceptedChild` and `RenderFragment AcceptedChild2`, but no `RenderFragment InvalidChild`.

Comment: But what I'm actually looking for, is some kind of validation for component type. To give a clearer example, let's say i have a data grid component and in the Columns render fragment, I want to only allow <DataGridColumn> components. I have updated the question's example .

Comment: @BogdanB Ah, okay, thank you for the clarification. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to make such child component limitations.